# Iteratively divide 2D array

Tags: c#

```
int numberOfThreads=4;
int division = (size * size) / numberOfThreads;
int startI = 0, startJ = 0;
int endI = division/size,endJ=division%size;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start I: {0} Start J:{1} && End I: {2} End J: {3}",startI,startJ,endI,endJ);
    startI = endI;
    startJ = endJ;
    //endI += (division/size); <-- how to find next ending index?
    //endJ += (division % size); <-- how to find next ending index?
}
```

I want to divide my 2D array into `numberOfThreads` parts. I know how to get the starting and ending index of first part, but I need help to find `endI` and `endJ` for rest of the array. For example if I had a 4x4 array which I want to divide in to 4 partsI would want
0,0 to 0,3 -> 1,0 to 1,3 -> 2,0 to 2,3 -> 3,0 to 3,4
If I want to divide it ino 8 parts:
0,0 to 0,0 -> 0,1 to 0,1 -> 0,2 to 0,2 -> 0,3 to 0,3 etc

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "Array Division"?

Comment: Are you just trying to split up your array into equal parts? For instance if you had something like `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]`, you would end up with `[1,2]`, `[3,4]`, `[5,6]`, and `[7,8]`?

Comment: Can you give an example with actual data and the expected result?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: @DanialAhmed - did my answer below help?

Answer (score 0):

So assuming I've understood correctly, I think you want to end up with something like this:

```
[
  [[0,0],[0,1][0,2][0,3]],
  [[1,0],[1,1][1,2][1,3]],
  [[2,0],[2,1][2,2][2,3]],
  [[3,0],[3,1][3,2][3,3]]
]
```

Or perhaps like this:

```
[
  [0,0],
  [0,1],
  [0,2],
  [0,3],
  [1,0],
  [1,1],
  [1,2],
  [1,3],
  [2,0],
  [2,1],
  [2,2],
  [2,3],
  [3,0],
  [3,1],
  [3,2],
  [3,3]
}
```

I'm still a little unclear what your original array looks like, but I'm guessing you're doing it from array dimensions rather than an actual filled array.

If this is all still the case I would do something like this for the 1st version:

```
public int[][][] GetArrayCoordinates(int xAxisSize, int yAxisSize)
{
    var coordinatesArray = new int[xAxisSize][][];

    for (int x = 0; x < xAxisSize; x++)
    {
        coordinatesArray[x] = new int[yAxisSize][];

        for (int y = 0; y < yAxisSize; y++)
        {
            coordinatesArray[x][y] = new int[] { x , y};
        }
    }

    return coordinatesArray;
}
```

This should give a multidimensional array (an array of arrays of arrays) with the x co-ordinate coming first in each set.

2nd version:

```
public int[][] GetArrayCoordinates(int xAxisSize, int yAxisSize)
{
    var index = 0;
    var coordinatesArray = new int[xAxisSize * yAxisSize][];

    for (int x = 0; x < xAxisSize; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < yAxisSize; y++)
        {
            coordinatesArray[index] = new int[] { x, y };
            index++;
        }
    }

    return coordinatesArray;
}
```

This should give you a jagged array (array of arrays) with the x co-ordinate coming first in each set.